# How do I fix audio issue on Dell Inspiron 3585?

Tags: laptop, audio, dell-inspiron

I have been trying to fix an issue with the audio connection on my Dell Inspiron 3585.

The issue is that whenever I plug in headphones the audio doesn't switch to them.

I have tried going via dell however they were unhelpful and insisted that it must be drivers and that I should update them. however when following their instructions it simply failed to update and that was the end of it.

If anyone has a better way to update drivers please answer.

I believe the issue may be the switch in the back of the audio jack that detects when it is plugged in (Im assuming this is how it works, I have seen this used before). I have tried to find a pinout for the connector however no luck, also the connector is mounted from the other side of the board which may complicate diagnostics.

If anyone knows where I can find the pinout for this connector I can determine if this is a software issue or a hardware issue.

Also if this is not the correct place to ask this please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a switched jack, though I can't find a schematic for one.
I can find replacements but they're sealed units, can't see inside…

[image]

You can get these for $£€ 10 - but for less than that you can get a can of contact cleaner, which will come in handy more than once.
Power the computer down, remove the battery, then spray in the jack socket & manoeuvre the plug in & out of the socket [gently] a dozen or so times.
Allow an hour to evaporate off before use.

Comment: can you leave a link to where you got that image please?

Comment: idk now. I just googled "Dell Inspiron 3585 audio jack replacement" & got pages of them

Comment: ok quick update: i have dissasembled the laptop and using a multimeter in continuity mode have determined that the switch is not working. the audio jack is the same as the one above. im going to try my luck with dell again this time with proof that the audio jack is bad. the laptop is still under warantee and dell suppoesedly provide a repair service.